# Click on DIV with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click on "retweet" with selenium. 
I found this way with **javascript**:

```
document.querySelector('[data-testid="retweet"]').click()
document.querySelector('[data-testid="retweetConfirm"]').click()
```

So I implemented in **selenium** with something like this:

```
firstJS = "document.querySelector('[data-testid=\"retweet\"]').click()"
secondJS  ="document.querySelector('[data-testid=\"retweetConfirm\"]').click()"
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script(firstJS)
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script(secondJS)
```

and i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\ProxyGiveaway\config.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\ProxyGiveaway\config.py", line 67, in main
    retweet(link, driver)
  File "C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\ProxyGiveaway\config.py", line 43, in retweet
    driver.execute_script(firstJS)
  File "C:\Users\Riccardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Riccardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Riccardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of null
  (Session info: chrome=1.2.3.4)
```

**EDIT:** I added some `time.sleep()` and the first line works, but not the second

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to page loading try adding wait until page load.

Comment: Can i use a specific function or a brutal time.sleep() ?

Comment: This reads more like a comment, not an answer. Can you elaborate on what you mean?